# Error 215 Bad Authentication Data Twitter API 1.1 to validate user accounts with PHP + Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, twitter, oauth

I have a website that uses the Twitter API (verrsion 1.1) with PHP and Zend framework 1 for validating the user name that is entered into a text input by a user of the application.

I created the app on Twitter and generated the Consumer Key (API Key), Consumer Secret (Secret API), Access Token and Access Token Secret.

***General permissions***: Read, write, and direct messages

***Tokens permissions***: Read and write

My PHP code for the authentication with Twitter is:

```
$config = array(
        'version' => '1.1',
        'signatureMethod' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'callbackUrl' => 'http://example/main/twitter',
        'siteUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth',
        'requestTokenUrl'=> 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
        'accessTokenUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
        'authorizeUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
        'consumerKey' => self::$_consumeKey,
        'consumerSecret' => self::$_consumeSecret
        );

$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('OAUTH_TWITTER');

$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer( $config );

$token = $consumer->getRequestToken();

$session->request_token = serialize($token);

$consumer->redirect();
```

When this code is executed, in the line:

```
$token = $consumer->getRequestToken();
```

returns the following error:

***Could not retrieve a valid Token response from Token URL: 
error code="215" Bad Authentication data.***

I do not know what I did because previously was working perfectly. I researched for 2 weeks and still can not find the solution. I tried to create the application again, regenerate keys and tokens and change the time zone of my server to UTC but has not been solved.

If you need more information about me, please let me know.

I appreciate any information you can give me. Regards.

PD: sorry by my bad english